# CSP violation when trying to whitelist site

Tags: community-builder, csp

I'm going through the Build a Community with Knowledge and Chat module on trailhead and keep getting the same CSP violation when I try to whitelist the snap-in chat in the community builder. I have made sure my security settings allow whitelisted third party scripts, but I get the CSP violation whenever I try to whitelist the snap-in chat. I've also tried adding it to trusted sites and still get the same violation. Is there anything else I should be doing?[image: Whitelist Error]

[image: Builder Security Settings]

Answer (score 1):

When adding sites to Trusted Sites (and often to the main Salesforce Trusted URLs list) add as https://*.salesforceliveagent.com to avoid duplication.  When I was adding the Zendesk Chat bot to an Experience site recently, I had to click through each CSP error url to find the next domain.  By the end of it, I had added:

- https://*.zopim.com
- https://*.zdassets.com
- https://*.zendesk.com

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Instead of trying to add the entire URL under whitelisted sites, Please try adding only until salesforceliveagent.com. Found the answer here. [stackexchange](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/252418/csp-problem-for-einstein-bot-in-lightning-community)

It solved my issue.